# Is it possible to specify default value for annotation field of another annotation type?

Tags: java, annotations, jls

```
public @interface InnerAnnotation {
    String value() default "hello";
}

public @interface OuterAnnotation {
    InnerAnnotation value() default ???
}
```

<strike>And one more case</strike>:

```
public @interface AnotherOuterAnnotation {
    InnerAnnotation[] value() default ??? UPD: {} 
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, its possible:

```
public @interface InnerAnnotation {
    String value() default "hello";
}

public @interface OuterAnnotation {
    InnerAnnotation value() default @InnerAnnotation(value = "Goodbye");
}
```

Comment: The Annotation-Array case is also possible with
InnerAnnotation[] value() default {@InnerAnnotation,@InnerAnnotation(value="fooBar")};